# How to show placeholder in TEdit

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

Is there any way to add a [placeholder](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/plactext.htm) text to an `edit`?

My only idea is to always manually set the color and the text of the given `edit` in its `OnChange` event, but it seems to be a bit tedious to me.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you want [TextHint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.TextHint)?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the TextHint. Please, make this comment an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I don't understand how could one upvote an answer and do not upvote a question ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is handled by the [`TEdit.TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.TextHint) property.  Note that it only works on XP and later with Visual Themes/Styles enabled for the app.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone got here like me through a web search, in cross-platform versions of Delphi using FMX, the placeholder display is handled by TEdit.TextPrompt.